# Asset not loaded with redirect_to with different layout in rails 5

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

Currently, I have 2 layouts say 'devise'(For not authenticated pages) and 'application'(For all pages after the login). For some reason after login when `redirect_to root_url` is executed the dashboard is loaded but any CSS and jQuery is not loaded. After refreshing the page, everything works fine. I am not sure what is causing this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*This is layout my files.*

**1. devise.html.erb**

```
<head>
  <title></title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <!-- Main css styles -->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag  'devise' %>

  <!-- Main javascript files -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'devise' %>
</head>
```

**2. application.html.erb**

```
<head>
   <title></title>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   <%= csp_meta_tag %>
   <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->

   <!-- Main css styles -->
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'%>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turbolinks works best when your JavaScript and CSS are consistent across different templates. If you must significantly change your scripts and styles between layouts I recommend that you add `data-turbolinks-track="reload"` to your asset tags:

```
<head>
  <title></title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <!-- Main css styles -->
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'devise', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  <!-- Main javascript files -->
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'devise', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>
```

---

```
<head>
   <title></title>
   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
   <%= csp_meta_tag %>
   <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> -->

   <!-- Main css styles -->
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'  %>
</head>
```

When Turbolinks notices a difference between a new page and the previous one, it will reload the page. This is also important to ensure that users download the most recently deployed assets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I ended up doing this only but did not want to answer my own question thinking this is a very simple thing that other people might be knowing, LOL.